# Is it possible to set Select element width in percentage?

Tags: html

I have a select element in an HTML page, I'd like to set its width to 100% (via CSS) but it doesn't work and the width only changes according to the width of the longest option.
Only when I set a width in pixels, it works.

Is it possible to set the width in percentage? or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check the parent element like  where your select option is there. The width of the parent element is the constraint for the child. You need to increase the width of the parent first.

Comment: That was the problem. The parent element didn't have a width defined.  Nice catch!

Answer (score 5):

Works for me here: http://jsbin.com/eraru

```
select {
    width: 100%;
}
```